# textnow api with nodejs not working logging in

Tags: node.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const textNow = require('textnow-api');


app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", function(request, response) {
  textNow.login("email", "'password").then(client => {
      console.log(`Logged in as ${client.username}`);

      textNow.fetchMessages(client.id, client.username).then(messages => {
          console.log(messages.map(message => `ID: ${message.id} | Message: ${message.message} | Sender: ${message.contact_value}`).join('\n'));
      });
  });
});

const listener = app.listen("80", function() {
  console.log("Your app is listening on port " + listener.address().port);
});
```

It only responds with a 400 error, even though I have the correct login. Can anyone please help me with this, or is it depricated and not working anymore?

Answer (score 0):

textnow-api is deprecated you can use it textbelt or Twilio api